# PDO wrapper class, bind dynamically?

Tags: class, dynamic, pdo, bind, wrapper

I am writing a simple PDO database class and I want to automatically bind results, but I'm not sure how I should be going about it, any help would be fantastic!

I really want the class to be as simple as possible so if you know of any other ways I could simplify this class that would be great.

Here is my database class:

```
class Database {

    private $connect;
    private $query;
    private $stmt;

    /**
    * @ Connect to the database and set PDO error mode
    */

    public function __construct() {

        try {
            $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog", "root", "root");
            $this->connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $error) {
            echo "ERROR: "  . $error->getMessage();
        }

    }

    /**
    * @ Perpare the database query
    */

    public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->connect->prepare($query);

        if ($action == 'insert' || $action == 'update') {
            reset ($array);

        }

    }


    /**
    * @ Bind the results
    * 
    */

    public function bind() {


                // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP

    }


    /**
     * @ Execute the query
     */

    public function execute() { 
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    /**
     * @ Return a set of results
     */

    public function results() { 
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
    * @ Return a single result
     */

    public function single() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to bind results or parameters?

Comment: I want to bind the results.

Comment: Are you sure? What results and where you want to bind them? As I can see, you have your *results* already all right returned form methods

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to PHP and programming, so my understanding is that normally this is how you would do a prepared statment using PDO....connect to DB - prepare statement - bindParam - execute. I want to cut out the bindParam bit.

Comment: With PDO you have this feature out of the box :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to bind parameters.

You don't actually need to bind them as PDO has a very handy feature of feeding `execute()` with array of values.

Though after taking a second look at this class I see not much point in it. as it giving you no benefit over PDO...

As you can have the same workflow with raw PDO

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->execute($array($email));
$row =  $stmt->fetch();
```

<s>class Database {</s>

```
    private $connect;
    private $query;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {

        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog";
        $this->connect = new PDO(, "root", "root". $opt);
        $this->connect->setAttribute();

    }
    public function prepare($query) {
        return $this->connect->prepare($query);

    }
    public function execute($stmt, $params) {   
        return $stmt->execute($params);
    }
    public function single($stmt, $params) {
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }

}
```

used as follows

```
$db = new Database();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$row =  $db->single($stmt, $array($email));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, so I can just prepare and execute a query without binding the params? Is there any senarios where I would need to bind them?

Comment: Calling stored procedures probably.